# How to make tuple subclass accept 2 arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tuples

I made a tuple subclass to add a property to a tuple. Using same logic as with a list subclass which works without problems. 
Code:

```
class TupleObject(tuple):
    def __init__(self, property, _tuple):
        super().__init__(_tuple)
        self.property = property

_tuple = TupleObject(property, (0, 0))
```

Throws error:

> TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

How could I make this work? Using this exact method with a list subclass works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because tuples are immutable, you need to override `__new__` to be able to modify the object before the instance is created.

```
class TupleObject(tuple):

    def __new__(cls, property, _tuple):
        self = super().__new__(cls, _tuple)
        self.property = property
        return self

_tuple = TupleObject('a prop', (0, 0))
_tuple, _tuple.property
```

Produces

```
((0, 0), 'a prop')
```

Comment: This code is broken; it will make `property` a *class* attribute of `TupleObject`, not an instance attribute, because the first argument is the class itself, not an instance to initialize. You need to receive the first argument as `cls` (to avoid confusing people), then do: `self = super().__new__(cls, _tuple)`, `self.property = property`, `return self`

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks for that, very good point.